# In what case is recommended to use one pod for many containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In what case is recommended to use one pod for many containers? Is it a good practice?

Comment: More information here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/

Comment: Yes , Thats what i'm looking for, Thanks